# Looking for a word describing what you are asking for in a trade

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

For example, if I want to trade my widget for someone else's trinket, I would refer to the widget as my "offer". What word could I use to describe the trinket, the item I hope to receive? The most appropriate word I can think of so far is the "ask". Are there any other words I should consider?

I would prefer a single word instead of a compound-word or phrase, but would still be curious to learn about them.

Comment: "reward" and "recompense" spring to mind but neither is quite right.

Comment: You can refer to your trade item any way you want. And so can whoever trades with you. Non-commercial exchanges are uncommon enough that no standard terms have evolved for them; in isolated speech groups with such customs, special vocabulary will form, but there's no guarantee it will be used (or even be meaningful) to people outside the speech group, nor will the same conventions usually be invented in independent speech groups. Like any evolutionary phenomenon, it starts as variation and becomes normal when there's no alternative.

Comment: A hypernym (but rare) is _desideratum_ (a/the thing required).

Comment: What's wrong with "request"?

Comment: [Ask](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ask) (noun) is in Merriam-Webster although it's tagged as informal.

Comment: You are describing a barter system: one thing is exchanged for another. https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/barter.asp#:~:text=Bartering%20is%20the%20exchange%20of,estimates%20of%20prices%20and%20goods.

Comment: A noun is not how the situation is handled by native speakers.  People trying to do a swap don't have a generic word  for the item they possess and a different generic word  for the item they want.

Answer (score 1):

In commerce, if you are able to treat one side as the seller and the other as the buyer, then the buyer provides *consideration* for the seller's *supply*.

> Consideration may be thought of as the concept of value offered and accepted by people or organisations entering into contracts. Anything of value promised by one party to the other when making a contract can be treated as "consideration": for example, if A signs a contract to buy a car from B for $5,000, A's consideration is the $5,000, and B's consideration is the car.
> [- wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consideration)

Here's an example of the terms in use:

- Consideration for a supply may be monetary or “in kind” in nature.
  [- Department of Health, Queensland](https://www.health.qld.gov.au/__data/assets/pdf_file/0029/398414/qh-imp-267-2-7.pdf)